# DataFrame splitting rows on multiple conditions into two sets, behaviour unexpected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to split my data in two sets (setA and setB) based on the properties and size of the data.
Given a dataframe of random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import random

# Create a DataFrame with random data
names = [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5)) for i in range(100)]
prop1 = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(100)]
prop2 = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(100)]
prop3 = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(100)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'prop1': prop1, 'prop2': prop2, 'prop3': prop3})
```

I want to add names to setA such that any property in setB is not present in setA.

This is my current code, I would expect the overlap to be 0 between setA and setB in the end. But as you can see when you run this code the overlap remains. I'm not understanding what is going wrong here. As far as i understand i:

1. Obtain a random set of properties.
2. Select all data points with these properties.
3. Add the data points to setA.
4. Remove selected data points from original set.
5. After reaching a threshold set the left-over data to setB.
6. SetB should contain no properties (for either prop1, and/or prop2, and/or prop3) of setA.

Much appreciated if anyone can point out where I am making the mistake.

```
# Initialize sets A and B
setA = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
setB = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Calculate the target size for setA (approximately 70% of the dataset)
target_size = len(df) * 0.7

while len(setA) < target_size and len(df) > 0:
    print(f'len at start of loop {len(df)}')
    # Take the first row from the shuffled DataFrame
    row = df.iloc[0]

    # Get values for prop1, prop2, prop3
    prop1, prop2, prop3 = row['prop1'], row['prop2'], row['prop3']

    # Filter DataFrame to find rows with the same values for prop1-3
    sim_1 = df[df['prop1'] == prop1]
    sim_2 = df[df['prop2'] == prop2]
    sim_3 = df[df['prop3'] == prop3]

    # similar_rows = df[(df['prop1'] == prop1) | (df['prop2'] == prop2) | (df['prop3'] == prop3)]

    # Remove rows from the original DataFrame
    indices = list(set(sim_1.index.tolist() + sim_2.index.tolist() + sim_3.index.tolist()))
    df = df.drop(index=indices)
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

    #assert nothing is left
    assert len(df[df["prop1"] == prop1]) == 0
    assert len(df[df["prop2"] == prop2]) == 0
    assert len(df[df["prop3"] == prop3]) == 0

    # Add the similar rows to setA
    # setA = pd.concat([setA, similar_rows])
    setA = pd.concat([setA, sim_1])
    setA = pd.concat([setA, sim_2])
    setA = pd.concat([setA, sim_3])

# Any remaining rows in df will go to setB
setB = df

assert setB[setB['prop1'].isin(setA['prop1'])].empty == True
```

**EDIT**

A concrete example of what i'm trying to do.

If the data is a collection of persons and what they eat for a certain catagory:

```
import pandas as pd

veggies = ['paprika', 'potato', 'potato', 'paprika', 'yam', 'zuchinni', 'zuchinni', 'yam', 'potato', 'potato']
fruits = ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'banana', 'cococonut', 'cococonut']
meats = ['chicken', 'cow', 'cow', 'chicken', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'fish', 'fish', 'cow', 'chicken']
names = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3', 'person4', 'person5', 'person6', 'person7', 'person8','person9','person10']

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'veggies': veggies, 'fruits': fruits, 'meats': meats})
```

In my first itteration I check for any of the first items being present, in this case the veggie paprika, the fruit apple and the meat chicken.

`df[(df['veggies'] == 'paprika') | (df['fruits'] == 'apple') | (df['meats'] == 'chicken')]`

Then the result would be:

```
index name      veggies fruits    meats
0     person1   paprika apple     chicken
1     person2   potato  apple     cow
2     person3   potato  apple     cow
3     person4   paprika apple     chicken
9     person10  potato  cococonut chicken
```

since we then also find potato and coconut and cow as new catagories we check for these.

`df[(df['veggies'] == 'potato') | (df['fruits'] == 'cococonut') | (df['meats'] == 'cow')]`

returning the following data

```
index name      veggies fruits      meats
1     person2   potato  apple       cow
2     person3   potato  apple       cow
8     person9   potato  cococonut   cow
9     person10  potato  cococonut   chicken
```

We add these together to find in total: (this would become setA)

```
index name      veggies fruits    meats
0     person1   paprika apple     chicken
1     person2   potato  apple     cow
2     person3   potato  apple     cow
3     person4   paprika apple     chicken
8     person9   potato  cococonut   cow
9     person10  potato  cococonut chicken
```

Then we check if we reach a certain threshold. Lets check for 50%. Since we have 6/10 data points we are above 50% and keep person1,2,3,4,9,10 as setA. The rest of the data is put to setB (person5, 6, 7, 8).

setB would be:

```
index name      veggies     fruits  meats
4     person5   yam         banana  sheep
5     person6   zuchinni    banana  sheep
6     person7   zuchinni    banana  fish
7     person8   yam         banana  fish
```

Now lets say we check the threshold at 70%, we find that we haven't reached it yet. So we look for the first new sample: person5 with yam, banana, sheep. Since we then also find zuchinni and fish the first possible solution above 70% is every person in one set we expect to fill setA completely while setB would be empty.

I don't mind which grouping gets in setA or setB, just that we can disentangle all the patterns between setA and setB to roughly a certain ratio. In reality each category has 1000s of classes and i'm finding a subset and which there is no overlap between classes in any of the categories.

Comment: In complement to your fully random example, can you craft a minimal reproducible example and provide the exact expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added in an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake, was indeed a logic error.

When i check all columns of my dataframe for similar items, I do not re-check for similar items to the similar items.

I simply added in a for loop doing X itterations and a break point when it does not find any more combinations.

```
    for i in range(100):
        sim_prop1 = similar_rows['prop1'].values
        sim_prop2 = similar_rows['prop2'].values
        sim_prop3 = similar_rows['prop3'].values
        
        similar_rows = df[(df['prop1'].isin(sim_prop1)) | (df['prop2'].isin(sim_prop2)) | (df['prop3'].isin(sim_prop3))]   

        #check if similar_rows got everything now
        if len(similar_rows['prop1'].values) == len(sim_prop1):
            break
```

Also the assertions now pass.

```
assert setB[setB['prop1'].isin(setA['prop1'])].empty == True
assert setB[setB['prop2'].isin(setA['prop2'])].empty == True
assert setB[setB['prop3'].isin(setA['prop3'])].empty == True
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it might be the logic at the last part of your code.

```
assert setB[setB['prop1'].isin(setA['prop1'])].empty == True
```

By applying the above logic, you are checking for the values in column 'prop1' only in both set A and B.

Even though the values are generated at random, there are bound to be repeated numbers.

Perhaps what you should do is to check across all columns (i.e. prop1 to prop3) between set A and B.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I suspect I'm making a logic error too. I understand there are to be repeated numbers, but shouldn't these all enter the same set? I check to find all entries with the similar property with `sim_1 = df[df['prop1'] == prop1]`. I add these to setA and remove them from the initial df. Then these properties should not be able to show up in setB if setB is just the remainder of the df?